# Difference between a*b and a*+b? Does the "+" denote Kleene plus or "or"?

Tags: automata

Me and a friend are study for a quiz and are trying to determine the difference between the two NFA's produce by the regular exressions `a*b` and `a*+b`. To us they seem functionally equivalent.

On the left is the nfa produced by `a*b` and on the right `a*+b`. Can you basically drop the `+` sign?

[image]

Comment: Yes, to me as well, they seem the same.

Comment: The right one does **not** produce $a^\ast + b$. Note that **every** accepted word of the right automaton has to end in $b$, but $a^\ast + b$ would also allow $a$ for example (and even the empty word).

Comment: @PhoemueX It believe that the "plus" sign in this case stands for Kleene plus, rather than "or". If this is the case, the combination of "star-plus" is indeed the same as "star".

Comment: This is where we were stuck, and still are. But I think the issue we face is with the comment above. We looked at the wikipedia page for regex, it says that `+` represents "one or more of the preceding character". But after using that definition to rework problems we had solutions to we realized it didn't make sense. // So it seems that there is sometimes a different meaning to `+` at different times. How can you tell what is meant?

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions there can be two meanings for the '+'.

First, it can be the 'Kleene' '+' that stands for several times and at least once. But when this is the case its superscript: For example $a^+$ stands for $\{a^n|n\geq 1\}$.

Otherwise it can stand for 'or'. in that case it's not superscript. For example $a+b$ stand for either $a$ or $b$.

For your example I think that the second expression is $a^*+b$ and is thus different to $a^*b$. the interpretation you gave was ${a^*}^+b$ for which you gave the automaton and which is equivalent to $a^*b$.